# Client Server tcp reset causes packet loss

Tags: java, networking, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient

I have a client(one machine) which sent the request to server(another machine).

Client sends request to server
Server processes request
Server sends response to client

In this scenario, when there is a TCP reset observed from client side, will there be a scenario where in my server wont be able to conjure/generate a response towards the client ?

I am using Java program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since client has reset the connection, meaning the old session between client and server has been closed.
In this case, it's impossible for server to send response back to the client within closed session.

Server can only send back response for an alive connection, which means the reset connection.